# Second div in this simple css parallax effect wont show up

Tags: html, css

This may be a really simple solution, but I cannot seem to find it.

I basically would like the second green div to show as well under the first brown one, so as you scroll down the page the green one will pop up as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .content {
                height: 1500px;
                background-color: brown;
            }
            .parallax-bg {
                padding: 400px 0;
                background-image: url(skyline.jpg);
                background-size: cover;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                -webkit-transition: all .02s ease;
                -moz-transition: all .02s ease;
                transition: all .02s ease;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            .parallax-bg h1 {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 100px;
                font-family: Arial;
                color: white;
            }
            #seconddiv {
                background-color: green;
                height: 1000px;
                padding: 100px 0;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
                .parallax-bg h1 {
                    color: blue;
                    font-size: 50px;
                    position: relative;
                    top: -100px;
                    color: white;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="parallax-bg">
                <h1>First Section</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="parallax-bg" id="seconddiv">
                <h1>Second Section</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use `jquery`?

Comment: For this purpose i would just like for the other div to show up but i would add the jquery later